# Java counter extra incremented inside for loop

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I have developed an application simulating queue-based systems, so practically simulating some queues and customers that come in and go out of them, like at a regular market. I did it for a single queue and now I am trying to do it for a given number of queues. For this, I am trying to use the number of threads equal to the number of queues to work in parallel.

The problem is with `iterations`, which instead of `1`, is `2`, and I do not understand why. This code is also running for 1 queue, and `queue[iterations]` was replaced by `queue[1]` because iterations is `2` instead of `1`.

Any ideas what the problem might be?
Thanks!

```
public class Simulation {
    static volatile int iterations=1;
    public Simulation(int minArrivingTime, int maxArrivingTime, int 
minServiceTime, int maxServiceTime, int nrQueues,
        int nrCustomers, int simulationInterval) {
    Customer[] sir = new Customer[nrCustomers + 1];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 1; i <= nrCustomers; i++) { // we create a new customer, and give it an id, a random arriving time
                                                // between the specified limits and a random service time between
                                                // the specified limits
        int arrivingTime = r.nextInt(maxArrivingTime - minArrivingTime) + minArrivingTime;
        int serviceTime = r.nextInt(maxServiceTime - minServiceTime) + minServiceTime;
        sir[i] = new Customer(i, arrivingTime, serviceTime);

    }
    Queue[] queue = new Queue[nrQueues + 1];
    Thread[] thread = new Thread[nrQueues + 1];
    for (iterations = 1; iterations <= nrQueues; iterations++) {
        System.out.println(iterations);
        queue[iterations] = new Queue();
        thread[iterations] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(iterations);
                String result = "Queue" + iterations;

                try {
                    for (int time = 0; time <= simulationInterval; time++) // we simulate each second untill the
                                                                            // simulation is over
                    {
                        result = "Queue" + iterations;

                        for (int i = 1; i <= nrCustomers; i++) {
                            if (sir[i] != null) {
                                if (sir[i].getArrivalTime() == time) // we 
iterate trough the array of customers,
                                                                        // 
and if
                                                                        // 
their arrival time is equal to the
                                { // current time, the customer enters the 
queue
                                    queue[1].enqueue(sir[i]);
                                    sir[i]=null;
                                    // 
result=result.concat(sir[i].toString()+" ");
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        Customer first = queue[1].getQueue().element();

                        if (first.getArrivalTime() + first.getServiceTime() <= time) {
                            first.setFinishTIme(first.getArrivalTime() + first.getServiceTime());
                            queue[1].dequeue();
                        }
                        for (Customer cus : queue[1].getQueue()) {
                            result = result.concat(cus.toString() + " ");
                        }
                        System.out.println(result);
                        System.out.println(" ");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    result = "The queue is empty";
                    System.out.println(result);
                }

            }
        });
        thread[iterations].start();
        // System.out.println(queue[1].getqueue[1]().get(1).toString());
        /*
         * for (Customer cus : queue[1].getqueue[1]()) {
         * System.out.println(cus.toString()); }
         */
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You understand that the variable is shared among the threads? So that every thread observe the exact same value?

Comment: Instead if iterating the queues you should better use a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) that sorts the persons according to their arrival time. Then you would only have to check the head of the queue.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I am really new to threads, but since I am using it only to create each thread, I thought that there shouldn't be any conflicts. Could you explain them please?

Comment: @Robert I know that there are better structures that can be used, I chose this one because it is easy and I can use it as a queue(FIFO). But  the point of this homework is working with multiple threads.

Comment: That is obvious. `iteration` is a shared variable, how would it be possible that two threads see something different? If there is one purse used by two persons, both will see the exact same content in it, isn't it?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I understand what you are saying, but how can I fix this and make it work? I tried using the volatile keyword, but it doesn't fix anything.

Comment: There is no good reason for you to use a share variable to iterate over something. That is at least the first problem. For the remaining I can suggest you to read about concurrent programming, synchronization and shared resources. Too broad for SO.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thanks a lot for all the advice!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès. Don't forget to close vote